# I can add only 15 products to a Bundle. How can I overcome this limitation?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2015

I was trying to add products to a Product Bundle and was able to add only 15 products after which I got an error saying "You can't add product to this bundle. You've reached the limit of 15."

Can this be overcome in someway? Can the limit be set or bypassed altogether?
Kindly advise. Thanks.

Comment: Is the CRM online or on premise ?

Comment: It is CRM Online. 2015.

Comment: Ok, that's important because being online severely limits the available "hacks"

Comment: Alright. So there's no way I can bypass this limitation? 15 products is the limit to add products to a bundle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CRM 2015 you are able to configure the limit of the product bundle, through the system settings, as specified in [Manage product catalog configuration](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/dn832125.aspx)

You need to navigate to **Microsoft Dynamics CRM > Settings > Administration > System Settings > Sales tab**. Then, from the sales tab find **Maximum number of products in a bundle** and set your desired value.

See the image below for the exact location in system settings:

[image: Set Maximum number of products in a bundle]